# If statement formula for excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Need help to write an if statement for the following:

```
Value
Cell G5
Income 0-$18000 no tax
$18001 - $37000  19% tax
>$37001  32.5% tax
```

Comment: What formula have you tried? We're not a script writing service, but we can try to help troubleshooting your script, or to make you understand how certain function works so you can expand from there.

Answer (score 0):

This gives the tax **percentage**:

```
=IF(G5<18001,0,IF(G5<37001,0.19,0.325))
```

This gives the tax **amount**:

```
=IF(G5<18001,0,IF(G5<37001,0.19,0.325))*G5
```

Answer (score 0):

I wished that you would give a proper explanation on your post along with what you've tried.

However, I will share with you what I have understood from the example you provided.

You need an IF statement formula that will check on cell G5 with the following conditions:

1. IF Income is **Less than** $18,000, *THEN* `No Tax`
2. IF Income is **larger than** $18,000 AND **Less than or Equal to** $37,000, *THEN* `Tax = 19%`
3. IF Income is **larger than** $37,001, *THEN* `Tax = 32.5%`

We don't know whether you need only to just show the Tax percentage or tax amount.

I will put both formula anyway.

To only show the Tax percentage:

```
=IF(G5>37000,0.325,IF(AND(G5>18000,G5<=37000),0.19,"No Tax"))
```

To get the total amount deducted from the Income (Income x Tax):

```
=IF(G5>37000,G5*0.325,IF(AND(G5>18000,G5<=37000),G5*0.19,"No Tax"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the Tax is on the slice of Income for example:
G5= 30000, you apply the percentage on the difference like:
Tax is :(30000-18000)*19%
not 30000*19%
you can use:

```
=IF(G5-18000>0,IF(G5-37000>0,(G5-37000)*32.5%+(37000-18000)*19%,(G5-18000)*19%),0)
```

you will have the amount corresponding to the Tax not percentage

In case no need to deduct, create a Table:

```
A       B  
0       0
18001   19%
37001   32.50%
```

If G5 is the income in H5 write:
=G5*IFERROR(VLOOKUP(G5,$A$1:$B$3,2,TRUE),1)
and you will have the amount of Tax